# Is it possible to tell Jetty/Guice to wait till all data is read from the request before invoking servlet?

Tags: java, jetty, guice

I have a web service with Guice managed servlets running over jetty 7, the request data is piped to Jackson for parsing. Is there a way to specify that all request data i.e. the input stream will have bytes equal to the request.getContentLength. I can make a blocking read in my code but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way.

Is there a common pattern to making this type of read async?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? There might be a way to achieve what you want, but it would help if we knew why. What you're asking to do seems counter-productive to me.

Comment: We want to consume a a stream in jackson but also log the request if jackson fails to parse it. So in our servlets we read the data into a byte array and then send that to jackson. This means we have to invoke the read until done code from all servlets. It seems cleaner if jetty did this for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write an input filter that reads and logs the input, then provides it on to the next filter down the line.  There is an example of this type of thing at [http://pragmaticintegration.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/logging-http-requests-jersey.html][http://pragmaticintegration.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/logging-http-requests-jersey.html]